# Is the base case $m=0$ in this proof by induction correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, induction, alternative-proof

Let $\Bbb J(n)$ the set of bounded intervals in $\Bbb R^n$, that is, if $I\in\Bbb J(n)$ there are bounded intervals $I_k\in\Bbb R$ such that $I=\prod_{k=1}^n I_k$, where the product is the cartesian product (we consider the empty set an interval in $\Bbb R$ and consequently also in $\Bbb J(n)$).

Then let any finite collection $I,J_1,J_2,\ldots, J_m\in\Bbb J(n)$, and I want to prove using strong induction that

$$I\setminus\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^m J_k\right)\text{ can be written as a union of finite pairwise disjoint intervals}\tag1$$

If I choose the base case $m=1$ then the proof becomes messy, but if I choose the base case $m=0$ then I find that $(1)$ is just $I$, so the base case holds trivially, and the rest of the proof is very simple.

> **Proof:** assume that a base case $m=0$ or $m=1$ holds, then we choose $(1)$ as hypothesis for all $1\le k\le m$ for some $m$. Then the induction step gives
>
> $$I\setminus\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{m+1}J_k\right)=\left(I\setminus\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^m J_k\right)\right)\setminus J_{m+1}\\=\left(\bigsqcup_{j=1}^r H_j\right)\setminus J_{m+1}=\left(\bigsqcup_{j=1}^r H_j\right)\cap J_{m+1}^\complement\\=\bigsqcup_{j=1}^r(H_j\cap J_{m+1}^\complement)=\bigsqcup_{j=1}^r(H_j\setminus J_{m+1})$$
>
> for $H_j\in\Bbb J(n)$, and using again the hypothesis we can write $H_j\setminus J_{m+1}$ as a union of disjoint intervals, so we are done.

There is a huge difference in difficulty in this proof choosing $m=0$ or $m=1$ as the base case, so I'm not sure if the proof for $m=0$ is completely right. Can someone confirm that we can choose $m=0$ in this proof without harm?

Also, I would like to know if someone knows how to handle easily the base case $m=1$. I tried but I lost myself in a mountain of intersections, unions and abstract thinking.

Of course, if someone knows how to prove $(1)$ in a different way I would like to know it.

---

Equivalently $(1)$ can be stated as: for any finite collection $J_1,J_2,\ldots,J_m\in\Bbb J(n)$ then $\bigcup_{k=1}^m J_k$ can be written as a pairwise disjoint union of intervals.

However, with this assertion, the induction step is as hard as the base case of the above when $m=1$.

---

**EDIT:**

Amazingly it seems that the base case $m=0$ is valid. Observe what happens with this reformulation of $(1)$:

> Let $I\in\Bbb J(n)$ and $\mathcal S\subset\Bbb J(n)$ finite. Then there is some finite $\mathcal B\subset\Bbb J(n)$ such that $$I\setminus\left(\bigcup\mathcal S\right)=\bigsqcup\mathcal B\tag2$$

Then from $(2)$ we can do induction over $|\mathcal S|$ and start with zero, so it seems that the base case of $m=0$ on $(1)$ is perfectly valid.

Comment: What are the elements of $\mathbb{J}(0)$?

Comment: Show the induction step. This makes it easier to decide whether it covers $m=0\implies m=1$

Comment: @Peter I will add the induction step to the question to clear things

Comment: The statement to prove could have been written more formally, but in any case you're not supposed to start $0$, as is suggested by $I,J_1,J_2,\ldots, J_m\in\Bbb J(n)$. Your base case $1$.

Comment: [Useful fact](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Set_Difference_of_Cartesian_Products).

Comment: Note that this proof of the induction step reduces the general proof of $P(m) \implies P(m+1)$ to the case of $P(0) \implies P(1)$. Of course, that doesn't work for $m = 0$ itself. The proof breaks down at "and using again the hypothesis". For $m = 0$, it's not the induction hypothesis you're using there, but the thing you're trying to prove.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the forum [Rincón matemático](http://rinconmatematico.com/foros/index.php) professor Carlos Ivorra [answered the question](http://rinconmatematico.com/foros/index.php?topic=103374.0) clearly so I will copy here a resume:

If $P(0)$ is true and $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ then the proof by induction is not automatically correct ([there is a classical example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color)), we also need to check that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ can be shown true *for all $n\ge 0$*.

In this case we can't prove $P(0)\implies P(1)$ so the base case $m=0$ is not useful for a proof by induction.

Comment: If $P(0)$ is true and (for all $n$) $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ is true, then the proof by induction _is_ correct and you get $\forall n. P(n)$. Now, if your induction step doesn't really prove $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ for all $n$, but only for $n > 0$, then it's not correct. Without having looked at any of the details of this particular problem, that is what might be going on here.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I see, thank you for the clarification.